# HTML not able to communicate with External Javascript Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I am implementing [Duo Auth](https://duo.com/) inside my angular 9 application. I have following files inside a folder for implementation of Duo auth.

|---index.html

|---abc.js

My index.html file looks like following

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="abc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="duo_iframe_wrapper">
        <iframe id="duo_iframe" title="Two-Factor Authentication"
        data-host="abc.duosecurity.com" 
        data-sig-request="abc"
        data-post-action="xyz">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**What Works**

If I simply open index.html in browser it works fine. Iframe loads perfectly

**What doesn't work**

What I did, I tried to transfer above index.html according to Angular component structure. I created a component and pasted this html in `abc.component.html`. Now I know that angular ignores script tags so I tried to load external js inside `angular.json`. When I routed to this component. Script loaded as expected. But iframe loaded nothing. Iframe body came empty.

I tried loading external js inside index.html of angular. Again script loaded but iframe came empty.
I tried to add the script tag on component level by following lines

```
 var dynamicScripts = ["../assets/js/custom/Duo-Web-v2.js"];
 for (var i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
   let node = document.createElement('script');
   node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
 }
```

Script loads fine but iframe comes empty.I tried loading it in constructor, ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit.

I think javascript is not able to communicate with iframe as it is doing in the first scenario.

**Note:** If I copy the exact html in angular's index.html and load javascript in it, it works fine.

So, Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Or even if it is possible or not?